Creating curves that blend into flat sides?
Greeting all,
I have a reference model here I'm trying to understand (learning as I go) .
I'd like to know how to break down this beautifully curved front section and understand how to blend it into the flat panels on the sides. Curves like this a definetly a weak spot for me so some ideas on how to achieve this shape would be awesome.
Cheers



There are ways to do this in Blender, but the illustrated model was almost certainly made in a CAD software

It's not clear what you want, do you want to redo from scratch the exact same shape?

You could begin with this shape (mirror it):

Move the edges to get that:

Add some edge loops:

Bevel the edge loops to round the shape:

Same thing for the perpendicular edge loops:

Result:


That's a great start - did you inset the faces on the side to provide a new edge loop to tidy up the geo in that last picture?

I've used the knife to extend the edge loops that are on the front
